# CRM export to excel failed - no log file

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I tried export Advanced find query to excel - and it failed with no log file details.

The number of records: 200000

I checked the below things:
1. No duplicate column with same name on View
2. I update MaxRecordsForExportToExcel to 1000000

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please translate that error message to English.

Comment: error occurred  please try again to apply this action. check if exist solution in Microsoft dynamics 365 community or go to the system manager of Microsoft dynamics 365 in organization, finally you can apply to microsot support/

Answer (score 0):

If its on-premise, you can troubleshoot by enabling trace on server for more detailed error message & fix it. For online no way to trace it.

This can be causing due to timeouts also. If its happening for small dataset or other entities as well, we can create a MS support ticket for assistance.

I would encourage you to do export smaller dataset, and merge the Excel files for final data as a workaround.